# Preserve Tooltips when exporting GraphPlot

Tags: html, wolfram-mathematica, export, tooltip

I have a very large, dense, labeled graph that I have visualized with GraphPlot. I would like to show the vertex labels with Tooltip, but must distribute them to people without Mathematica. Unfortunately Tooltips are stripped when exporting to PDF.

I next tried exporting to HTML. The tooltips are preserved, but when my graph is converted to a .gif, it is too small to see. Is there a way to specify the size of images when exporting to HTML?

Or, can anyone help me figure out how to export to a different format while preserving Tooltips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You merely need to specify an explicit `ImageSize`.  This can be given in the initial `GraphPlot`, or amended using `Show` as follows:

```
gp =
 GraphPlot[
   {3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, {3 -> 6, "edge 3->6"}, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6},
   EdgeLabeling -> Automatic
 ]

Export["graphplot.html", Show[gp, ImageSize -> 800], "HTML"]
```